# How the "ON" function works in this query? is the ON here serves as a WHERE function?

Tags: mysql

Need some advise here, saw the "ON" but it has () and it's likely look like a WHERE to me.. is this correct?
what I know is using of ON as tablename1.col=tablename2.col but not in this way.
Guys, I would like to be enlighten.
thanks in advance

```
SELECT DISTINCT(m_employee.company_code) AS company_code
                ,m_loan.loan_no 
                ,m_loan.loan_date   
                ,m_loan.employee_id 
                ,m_employee.last_name   
                ,m_employee.first_name  
                ,m_loan.employee_principal_amort AS principal   
                ,m_loan.employee_interest_amortization AS interest
                ,rtc.charge_formula AS pent 
                ,r_loan_header.comp
                ,m_loan.interest_rate
                ,m_loan.principal_balance
            FROM m_loan     
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  r_transaction_charge rtc       
                ON (rtc.transaction_code = 'LOYA' 
               AND rtc.charge_code = 'PENT')
```

Comment: The `ON` clause contains the `JOIN` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql `ON` is used to define the condition on which a JOIN is to be built or `ON` clause contains the `JOIN` condition. It doesn't have `()` with its syntax, `()` is used to combine a part of condition. Just like in your example:

```
ON (rtc.transaction_code = 'LOYA' AND rtc.charge_code = 'PENT')
```

here `()` is used to specify that `AND` is used with these two conditions, and you can omit these `()` if you want. Specifically `()` is used in condition like:

```
WHERE (age = 20 AND gender = 'male') OR (age = 18 AND gender = 'female')
```

Answer (score 1):

The ON clause is used to create a  [join between tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). The join is conditional, so in that respect it shares semantic similarity to a WHERE clause.

Comment: @axiac  true it is part of the syntax of outer joins as well, I will correct.